# Verb (as adjective) + subject vs subject + verb

Tags: adjectives

Which one is correct or seems more natural?

- Please, walk on the path provided.
- Please, walk on the provided path.

I've looked it up on google and the former seems more common than the latter, but I can't see much difference between them.

Comment: There isn't much difference. It's just that *idiomatically*, we usually put "past tense form functioning as adjective" words ***after*** the noun. Parse it as a shortening of *...the path [**which has been**] provided*, if you like. Putting it *before* the noun is often seen as a "marked" usage - people may "invent" all sorts of reasons why they express or understand some subtle difference in various contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see, I have read about **reduced relative clauses** in the past and although I wasn't sure whether this was a case of it, I have started to think that it might be. Could confirm that?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause

Comment: "Provided" is not an adjective - it's a verb. In your first example, "provided" is a past-participial clause modifying "path", and in the second a verb phrase as an attributive modifier of "path".

Comment: It can't be an adjective since it doesn't have the properties of an adjective. For example, it can't be modified by "very", and it can't occur as complement to complex-intransitive verbs like "become" (* "It became quite provided") nor complex-transitive verbs like "find" (* "I found it quite provided"). It is a verb in both your examples.

Comment: MAC - as can be seen from @BillJ's comment, I don't have the appropriate grammatical terminology. But *in practice* (from the perspective of a natural speaker, not a grammarian), there's no real difference between, say, *I don't think there's any **implied difference*** and *I don't think there's any **difference implied***.

Comment: I think that  "Please, walk on the path provided" is hugely more natural and common than "Please, walk on the provided path".

Answer (score 0):

Please note as Fumble Finger has rightly observed , there is not much of a  difference.  In fact the link as here in below  harps on the same string.
httpbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv133.shtml

Adjectives are used attributively. The same is true about past participle/ present participle adjectives. When  we use them as post modifiers our main focus is primarily to lay emphasis on the qualities. Post positive use is preferred for reduced adjective clauses or when the participle is part of larger adjective phase.

Path provided/ provided path doesn't present any such dichotomy. Both are correct but, to my mind, " provided path" is a narrowed version. "Path provided" is a liberal invitation to follow the instructions.